# Left-over-right Kittel

Tags: product-recommendation, kittel

Does anyone know where to get a kittel which buttons left-over-right? I know at least a few people who would prefer not to buy into the right-over-left market.*

---

*This is supposedly a kabbalistic practice, however [non-Jewish Russian](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/Prokudin-Gorskii-05.jpg) [folk garb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosovorotka) also buttons that way, leading me to conclude that this was a retcon of an already prevalent practice, rather than an original rationale.

Comment: You're saying they don't want to follow the kabbalah's implied suggestion because they think chukat hagoyim is a bigger issue?

Comment: @SAH, I don't follow it because it is a minhag shtus, which has been retconned to be justified by a sefer composed ~1000 years after its attributed author died.

Comment: I don't recall if it's Bobov or Satmar that has the left over right custom regarding all clothing. (Years ago, I taught a computer class, and as 2 men looked similar, I couldn't distinguish them until one pointed out the button direction. But, I don't recall what sect he was.) At any rate, once you can find out which it is, you might find this in a Williamsburg or Boro Park store.

Comment: I just thought of another way to find out. If I recall correctly, the kittel used for a dead person is left over right. Why not contact a Jewish funeral home and ask them where they get their supplies? Just make sure you tell them that you're not planning to die that soon!

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a product-recommendation which falls within the parameters of the tag.

Comment: @SAH - Most Yekkes (like NoachMiFrankfurt here) do not follow the minhagim laid out in the Zohar, simply because they do not believe the Zohar was composed by the Rashbi.

Comment: @SAH, here is a photo of the Maharam Schi"ck, a Hungarian talmid of הר׳ המקובל מוהר"ר החתם סופר זצ"ל (himself a Jekke) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Schick

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59301/discussion-between-ezra-and-noach-mifrankfurt).

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt So you don't think the Rashbi wrote the Zohar?

Comment: @SAH, how could he? Rashb"i ז"ל was opposed to some of the 'inyanim which are brought in the Zohar, the language is inconsistent with his own (and clearly influenced by mediæval Spanish), and a sefer from the period of Chaza"l can't magically appear with all of this inconsistency and be authentic. It was very clearly written by Moshe de León and his school, although some portions likely have greater antiquity (Chassam Saufer: http://parsha.blogspot.com/2011/06/chasam-sofers-position-that-zohar-is.html )

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I realize that yours is the academic opinion, but don't know why--if it were "very clear" that Rashbi were not the author of the Zohar--most of today's gedolim would believe he were

Comment: @SAH do you disregard the gadlus of the Chassam Saufer, the Ya'ave"tz, the Noda' BiYhudoh, R' El'ozor Fleckeles, and the numerous other gedolei Kehillos Ashkenaz who were opposed to the usage of the Zohor for halochoh  or minhogim.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt It looks like you're in a position to answer my other question about halacha from the Zohar, but I don't really see what that has to do with Rashbi. Do you have a source for the Chasam Sofer's inclusion on this list? I'd be fascinated to see it

Comment: @SAH, see my first response to the Rashb"i question. I linked an article from Josh Waxman's ParshaBlog.

Answer (score 1):

[This Kittel](http://tzitzit.tallit-shop.com/pleated-kittel/) appears to be left over right.